# Updating multiple IP devices on network

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, ip

How to update, configure or gain access to multiple IP devices on a network using multithreading concept in python.

Comment: Oh you need the code?  I'll be sure to get right on that.

Comment: Wait I just remembered we don't provide code writing as a service.  Better luck next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. import threading and socket
2. Send a ping to all ip devices on a network using ip.net_hosts()
3. If successful response has been received, acquire a lock on the device.
4. Run your update logic.
5. Release the lock.